# Fix Synergy so it works on Login/Locked screen

Tags: windows, synergy, windows-services

I like [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) -- I have it set up on a mac (server) and windows 7 (client), but I have a couple problems with it on windows:

- I'd like it to start automatically on boot
- It doesn't work on the login/locked screens

I've seen some sparse mentioning of installing Synergy as a service, so I tried this in the windows command line:

```
sc create Synergy binPath= "c:\Program Files\path\..." start= auto
```

This adds the service, but starting the service results in an error: "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install the windows beta 1.4.2. It contains a menu options to install the service. You might need to disable UAC, but that might just be for using Synergy on the UAC dialogs.

Answer (score 5):

Run 1.4.2 as Administrator (right click in start menu and select run as admin), click the install service, then bring up the services dialog (from manage computer) and find synergy and click start. You should have entered in the dialog what it connects to if it is a client.
Make sure it is set as auto start.

Comment: Thanks! This is correct, but Bostonvaulter also is correct and got to me first.